# Catholic remembrance services for a death elsewhere?

Tags: catholicism, mass, funeral

If a person dies and is given a Catholic funeral and service, but that person has a lot of family in a location that was too far away to attend the service, is there an official Roman Catholic service that can be held as a sort of "satellite funeral" for those who were unable to attend the actual service but wish to remember the person religiously? If not, what would usually be done in this situation?

I hope that made sense; I was struggling a bit with the wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Catholic remembrance services for a death elsewhere?**

First of all, Catholic funeral services are traditionally held on the day of death and/or on the day of the funeral of an individual. In addition to this, some Catholics have a Requiem Mass celebrated on the 30th day after their death or even then the 1st anniversary of their death, in order to facilitate the need for others to attend the original date of the funeral services, which were unattainable by some for whatever reason.

In the [**Tridentine Rite**](https://media.musicasacra.com/pdf/romanmissal_classical.pdf) this was more predominant than in the  New Rite, but nevertheless remain quite valid. It could be held anywhere and not only in the local of the person who died.

Just a reminder that eulogies not allowed at Catholic funerals. If any anniversaries are held in the Church some rules must be upheld.

> The Vatican made that clear in 1989. In its Revised Order of Christian Funerals, it stated that "a brief homily based on the readings should always be given at the funeral liturgy, but never any kind of eulogy."
>
> In 2000, Pope John Paul II restated the prohibition when he wrote “at the funeral mass there should, as a rule, be a short homily, but never a eulogy of any kind.”
>
> The rationale is that eulogies are often considered the centrepiece of the service, and therefore detract from the mass and its central message, which is the Christian meaning of death. - [The rationale is that eulogies are often considered the centrepiece of the service, and therefore detract from the mass and its central message, which is the Christian meaning of death.-[Eulogies not allowed at Catholic funerals](https://www.thepeterboroughexaminer.com/news/peterborough-region/2013/01/10/eulogies-not-allowed-at-catholic-funerals.html)

As for Requiem Masses via live feed or some other form of social media, you will have to talk to the pastor involved in these arrangements.

Comment: FWIW, I have been invited to attend a memorial service for an old comrade in arms, which got delayed due to COVID (people could not travel and public gathering restricitons).  Is your answer incluse of Memorial Services?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I do not see why not as long as arrangements could be made with the pastor in question.